# How am I supposed to go to any fragment from an activity?

Tags: javascript, android, xml, android-studio, android-fragments

This is the activity code. I'm tryin to go to the fragment when I click on a button. But I don't know how to do it. And when I use `intent` like the `intent report`, it asked me to declare the `shopping_cart` (fragment) at manifest.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case (R.id.shopping_cart):
            

        case (R.id.report):
            Intent report;
            report = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Report.class);
            startActivity(report);
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: You don't _"go to a fragment from an activity"_. A fragment (or several of them) is (or are) contained within an activity. You can go to another activity or you can show/hide a fragment within one activity. The answer below points to `FragmentManager` which is the right way.

Comment: I'm supposed to go from fragmentA > activity(menu) > fragmentB

Answer (score 0):

Just Do This For Going Activity To Fragment

```
 public void replace(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

And In Button Click Just Put Below Code

```
replace(new FragmentName());
```

Comment: so I just add the `replace (new FragmentName( ))` under the `case (R.id.shopping_cart)` ?

Comment: the button is the `menu` "button"

Comment: Yes, Just Add replace(new Report())

Comment: If You use FrameLayout Then